# how to extract space state matrices form workbench 2022 model using matlab

Tags: matlab, state-space, ansys

I need to extract state space matrices of Ansys-Workbench 2022 model. I need to import this Ansys-Workbench model (after modal analysis is done ) to Matlab , then do post-processing to it in order to extract A,B, and C matrices(state space matrices).
Is it possible ? How to import this model to Matlab? How to extract A,B,and C matrices (state space matrices) then in Matlab ?

Comment: All those sofware you mention are likely unknown to most people. Can you narrow down your problem? We can help if you have a particular file you may be able to load, but otherwise its extremely unlikely you will find anyone who knows what Ansys-Workbench and SPMWRITE and APDL are in the MATLAB community.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation you're in. There is indeed a way to extract State-space matrices in ANSYS Mechanical. You can include the **SPMWRITE** command in your simulation tree to achieve this. Here's how you can do it:

**Extracting State-space Matrices:**
Right-click on the analysis you want to perform (modal, harmonic response, etc.) and add a "command (APDL)" where you can write APDL commands directly.
Utilize the "ExportStateSpaceMatrices.mac" macro (from 2009, quite old, I hope ANSYS will do something about it eventually), which is generally located in the Ansys installation folder (default path is usually C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v221\aisol\DesignSpace\DSPages\macros). Open it with a text editor and copy-paste the code into the APDL command you created. You can edit it, but i can't help you with that, sorry but i don't know APDL language yet. I think another way is to write "/input, ExportStateSpaceMatrices,mac,'C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v221\aisol\DesignSpace\DSPages\macros'" in the command (APDL), but i have to try it though.
Run the simulation, and the commands will be executed, generating an ".spm" file in the results folder of the project (inside “project_folder\dp0\SYS-n\MECH"). You can find it quickly by toggling the visualization of "files" in the Workbench interface (top-left corner: View - files). The file.spm will contain inputs (forces. I don't know how it works for pressures or other loads), outputs (user defined remote points), and State-space matrices A, B, C (D is usually 0 – zero - and you can declare it by yourself in MATLAB).

**Challenges and Workarounds:**

1. **Modal Displacements Only:** The macro supports only modal
   displacements (or modal velocities/accelerations). If you need to
   work with strains or other outputs, you'll need to process the data
   in MATLAB.
2. **Random Order:** Inputs and outputs inside the .spm file are randomly
   ordered. Sorting them may require a MATLAB script. I still haven’t figured out how to sort them directly from the analisys settings.
   Be cautious, as rearranging input/output vectors will require reorganizing B, C, and
   D matrices, since they deal with inputs and outputs.
3. **Matrix Slicing:** When extracting a high number of states (e.g., more
   than 50 modes or 100 states), you'll notice a limitation in text
   file length: a single row of matrices A and C will correspond to two
   consecutive rows in the text file, indicated by a backslash. You'll
   need to "slice" the raw matrix and recombine it properly to obtain the matrix you are looking for.

I’m currently running a simulation and waiting for the results to come out. Yesterday I obtained the spm file, but today I made few corrections to the model and something is not working anymore. (Mine is a trial-and-error approach, but it works... much).

I really hope this can help you or whoever will read this thread.

Best regards,

Giovanni